# Auto Refreshing ImportXML Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a sheet that imports data from a site, there are about 10 imports all slightly different. I want a way that I could update that every five minutes or so. I know there are scrips to do it but when I tried to use one it would just put ?update at the end and mess up the entire import. I can show the script I am using. It is from 4 years ago and maybe it is outdated. Any help would be appreciated.

Also just having a script that changes the = to nothing then adds it back again or something would work I guess.

Here is the script I am using

```
    function RefreshImports() {
  var lock = LockService.getScriptLock();
  if (!lock.tryLock(5000)) return;             // Wait up to 5s for previous refresh to end.

  var id = "Sheets ID";
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet Name");
  var dataRange = sheet.getDataRange();
  var formulas = dataRange.getFormulas();
  var content = "";
  var now = new Date();
  var time = now.getTime();
  var re = /.*[^a-z0-9]import(?:xml|data|feed|html|range)\(.*/gi;
  var re2 = /((\?|&)(update=[0-9]*))/gi;
  var re3 = /(",)/gi;

  for (var row=0; row<formulas.length; row++) {
    for (var col=0; col<formulas[0].length; col++) {
      content = formulas[row][col];
      if (content != "") {
        var match = content.search(re);
        if (match !== -1 ) {
          // import function is used in this cell
          var updatedContent = content.toString().replace(re2,"$2update=" + time);
          if (updatedContent == content) {
            // No querystring exists yet in url
            updatedContent = content.toString().replace(re3,"?update=" + time + "$1");
          }
          // Update url in formula with querystring param
          sheet.getRange(row+1, col+1).setFormula(updatedContent);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  // Done refresh; release the lock.
  lock.releaseLock();

  // Show last updated time on sheet somewhere
  sheet.getRange(12,2).setValue("Rates were last updated at " + now.toLocaleTimeString())
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### You can write a script that retrieves the formula from the specified cell and sets it back to the same cell on a timer

For this you need:

- Retrieve the formula with [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getformula)
- Set the formula back into the same cell with [getFormula()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulaformula)
- [Bind](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) an [installable time-driven trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) to your function specifying the desired interval

Sample:

```
function setMeOnTrigger() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var cell = sheet.getRange("C1");
  cell.setFormula(cell.getFormula())
}
```

Comment: The only problem is all 11 XML Imports I have that need updating are different slightly

Comment: Nothing stops you from implementing 11 indvidual `getFormula` and `setFormula` requests inside the same function. Also, if the cells containing the formulas are all in an adjacent range, you can use directly `getFormulas` and[`setFormulas`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas) instead to reduce the amount of calls. Otherwise, you can implement the requests in different functions running on different timers - depending on how often you want to update which formula.

Comment: I tried that roughly, but It was very janky and eventually messed up the entire spreadsheet. I am sorry, I am not entirely proficient in GoogleScript

Comment: What exactly was the problem?